# Data gets automatically deleted if the node is recently created in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an app which has a student and teacher model and whenever I create a new course and try to add students to it, their details get uploaded but then suddenly gets deleted automatically. But once the course becomes a little old like around 30-40 mins later I can easily add students and they stay there.

Here is a part of my code where student is added here user is the student to be added

```
reference.child(user.getUserId()).setValue(user).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e("Problem",e.toString());
    }
});
reference_stu = database.getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUserId()).child("Studies")
        .child(subjectId);
reference_stu.child("instructor").setValue(inst_id);
reference_stu.child("Subject_Id").setValue(subjectId);
```

database reference is set to the course
and another reference for student is set to the course in students node where the courses that it studies are listed.

Comment: There is nothing in Firebase's inherent behavior or in the code that you shared that explains why data would get deleted automatically. If the course gets deleted, look for calls to `removeValue` in your code that could be causing this. If the course gets overwritten instead, look at all your `setValue` calls on the reference to that course to see which one could be causing it.

Comment: Have you tried Frank's recommendation?